# Can USB-C cable/port become corrupted and only transmit partial power/data? Or would it stop working completely if broken?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, usb, usb-c

I plugged my usb-c cable into my device pretty roughly and felt/heard something crumple, and I'm thinking I may have damaged it. Everything seems to be working fine though, but I'm worried that its charging/data might be diminished. Or if it was damaged would it just not work altogether?

Comment: It depends. Send pics... ;-)

Comment: @TurboJ there's nothing visually damaged from what I can see, I tried taking pics but my camera can't focus on it :(

Comment: _I'm worried that its charging/data might be diminished_  Keep using the cable and see if there is some change to the charging rate or data transmission.